# Format psd generated html to email compatible html

Tags: html-table, html-email, psd, html-generation

I am working for a project where I need to convert the html that photoshop generates to email client compatible.

Once I receive a psd file, I need to create slices and then generate the html. The problem is that the generated html has tables with rowspan and colspan. I then manually remove these colspans and rowspans and nest tables to achieve the same layout.

My question is, is there a library or something that I can use to automate this task?

Below is just an example, the real problem can include various colspans and rowspans in any specific order.

Example -

PS code ->

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="3">First row 3 columns</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Second row first column</td>
    <td>Second row second column</td>
    <td>Second row column column</td>
</tr>
```

I will then have to code this as -

```
<tr>
    <td>First row 3 columns</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Second row first column</td>
                <td>Second row second column</td>
                <td>Second row column column</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I work for a company who deliver many HTML emails everyday, i'm email HTML developer, and we use Fireworks (CS6, he's not in the CC..) to generate nested tables (some options are to define).

G.